# Is the media grid class gone from Twitter bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use the media grid class and its just showing up as an unordered list. I did a search in the bootstrap.css and can't find media-grid. Or is there a new method to achieve the media grid look? Thanks

```
  <!--Media grid-->
      <ul class="media-grid">
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/290x200" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/290x200" />

            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/290x200" />
            </a>
        </li>

      <!--media grid-->
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found the answer, .media-grid has changed to .thumbnails.